# How to setup a Django App on OpenShift DIY with virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, openshift

As RedHat openshift doesn't support Python 2.7, I choose to use Do-It-Yourself (DIY) application.

I could able to install python 2.7, setuptools, PIP successfully using an amazing [tutorial](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/enabling-python-27-on-a-paas-with-the-openshift-diy-app-type). Now I want to setup a VirtualEnv and install Django and other libs in it.

So, is there any similar (as mentioned above: step by step process) tutorial to configure?

Comment: As of the last few months, you can run both 2.7 and 3.3 python as community carts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a example app which runs on Python 2.7, Django 1.4 powered by uWSGI (or Gunicorn; dev choice) and Jenkins CI.. Of course using Virtualenv

https://github.com/ksurya/openshift-diy-py27-django-jenkins (dead - repo gone), alternative is https://github.com/joskid/openshift-diy-py27-django-jenkins (seams to be the same)

The other similar example projects:

1. https://github.com/ehazlett/openshift-diy-py27-django
2. https://github.com/zemanel/openshift-diy-django-example